# Flash Reading by JTAG

Tags: jtag

I'm trying to read the flash memory of a microcontroller MPC5606B from Motorola. I saw his pins and saw that it uses jtag to perform debug, so I'm trying to use it JTAG interface to read its flash content.

I read the MPC's flash content using a tool (UPA) and a PC, however, I want to do it by my own, using my own embedded hardware without the PC's tool. I read about JTAG standard( JTAG_IEEE-Std-1149.1-2001 ), and some videos and explanations on the internet. I read about TAP controller state diagram and read about some instructions too.

In order to better understand the JTAG reading, I Used the PC's tool to read the MCP's flash and an osciloscope to see how the communication is performed, however, the communication has almost 10s of duration. So, I filled the entire flash with zeros and read the memory, in this way, I was able identify the reading of memory using the osciloscope. However, although I can identify the reading of memory using the osciloscope, I can't determine yet the exact sequence of commands to perform the reading. The time of reading is too big, almost 10s.

So, before to go more deep, I would like to know if there is some kind of protection to access the flash memory. I tried to understand the beginning of the communication, I can identify the progress in the TAP controller's state machine, but I was not able to understand what this steps means and why it is done. So, I would like to know:

1) Can I determine if the communication has some kind of protection ? I really need to know it before to go further in the task because I need to know the task's complexity level before to go more deep

2) Although I read  about the JTAG standard and the TAP controller state machine, I was not able to say what sequence of comands I need to read the flahs content.

Abaixo está a leitura do flash do MPC5606B realizada pela ferramenta com o auxílio do PC. The image is composed of a sequence of images. The first is the image of the communication in full, the second is the beginning of the communication, there is an arrow indicating where it was withdrawn.

[image]

This was my interpretation until now

FIGURE 1:

1.1 - (TMS = 1) Test-Logic-Resset

1.2 - (CLK wide pulse) I do not know why.

1.3 - (8 pulses of CLK, TMS = 1)

Since TMS did not came out to 1 I understand that it did not quit Test-logic-Reset

1.4 - (TMS = 0, 1 pulse clock) enters Run-Test-Idle

---

FIGURE 2:

2.1 - (TMS = 1, 2 clock pulses) Goes to the "Select IR-Scan" state

2.2 - (TMS = 0, 2 pulses of clock) Go to the state "Shif-IR"

2.3 - (TMS = 0, 4 clock pulses) Remains in "Shift-IR"

TDI: 1000
TDO: 1000
2.4 - (TMS = 1, 1 clock pulse) Goes to the "Exit1-IR"

2.5 - (TMS = 1, 1 clock pulse) Goes to the status "Update-IR"

2.6 - (TMS = 0, 1 clock pulse) Goes to the "Run-Test-Idle"

---

FIGURE 3:

3.1 - (TMS = 1, 1 clock pulse) goes to the "Select DR-Scan" state

3.2 - (TMS = 0, 2 clock pulses) Go to the status "Shif-DR"

3.3 - (TMS = 0, 31 clock pulses) Go to the "Shif-DR" state

The 32 clock cycles are equivalent to 4 bytes:

TDI: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
TDO: 0xB8 0x0C 0x27 0x54 (10111000 00001100 00100111 01010100)

3.4 - (TMS = 1, 1 clock pulse) Goes to the "Exit1-DR"

3.5 - (TMS = 1, 1 clock pulse) Goes to the status "Update-DR"

3.6 - (TMS = 0, 1 clock pulse) Goes to the "Run-Test-Idle"

Comment: Daniel did you find way for reading MPC5606BK?

Comment: @autofan1965, I tried, but I didn't need it anymore,  so I stopped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interpreting JTAG transactions by hand can be pretty tiresome. If you can export your data to a more or less universal data format, like VCD or even a CSV file, you can use [Sigrok and Pulseview](http://sigrok.org/) to decode your data. This will decode the low-level JTAG data; if you know the specifics of the controller like TAP register layout and command set, you can extend Sigrok with a decoder that runs on top of the existing IEEE-1149 decoder.

[image: jtag]

Comment: I'm using PulseView to decode the communication, it was a very good advise, I really thank you. However, I stopped decodding for a while, before to go further I need to know if there is some kind of protection / Security in MPC5606B because, otherwise, this work could be worthless. Do you know something about it ?

Comment: From the nature of the question I thought it was something obscure, but apparently there are plenty of docs out there. I would suggest reading reference manual: http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/MPC5606BRM.pdf . You are interested in sections 2.4.5, 5.1.3, 35.

Answer (score 5):

Your interpretation looks pretty close to me. However, this is very low-level view, you need to bring it back to the higher level, at least IR/DR. For example, the whole exchange 1-3 can be summarized as:

Write IR=0b100 (8), read DR=0x2AE4301D

(DR bits are shifted in from the lowest one, so you need to swap the bit string)

This IR value is very close to the standard IDCODE(4), so I think there is an off-by-one in your interpretation and this exchange is reading the device ID. In fact, the value 0x2AE4301D  matches the one for MPC5606BF I found in [this document](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN4477.pdf).

As for actual flash reading, I doubt it's done using raw JTAG commands. AFAIK the common ways of reading flash are the following:

1. using boundary scan, set and read the CPU pins connected to the flash chip; basically turning the CPU into a bit-bang flash programmer. This obviously only works with external flash so probably not your case
2. using custom chip-specific debugging commands, read and write the flash device I/O registers in the CPU memory space.
3. using custom chip-specific debugging commands, upload a small flasher program into the CPU's RAM and let it execute. The program would chunks of flash into a RAM area which can then be fetched via JTAG back to the host. by setting the register state before each execution, different parts of flash could be accessed.

I would recommend you to use a program like urJTAG or OpenOCD to perform high-level JTAG manipulations (like sending IR and reading DR) if you want to reproduce what the flasher program is doing. urJTAG also has a mode to brute-force possible IR values which may let you discover the vendor-specific commands.

Comment: I identified the IDCODE in the communication's log, your observations and tips were very useful, thank you very much. However, I stopped decodding for a while, before to go further I need to know if there is some kind of protection / Security in MPC5606B because, otherwise, this work could be worthless. Do you know something about it ?

Comment: since the other flasher works, I doubt there's a strong protection, if any. In any case, that's a different question.