# Flash reading by JTAG in MPC5606B

Tags: jtag, flash

I'm using MPC5606B and I would like to know what kind of issues I would have, concerning protection\encryption  if I tried to read its flash content by JTAG using an external device.

I was able to read the MPC's flash content using a tool (UPA) and a PC, however, I want to do it by my own, using my own embedded hardware without the PC's tool. So, I studied about JTAG standard( JTAG_IEEE-Std-1149.1-2001 ), and about TAP controller state diagram. In order to better understand the JTAG reading, I Used the PC's tool to read the MCP's flash and an osciloscope to see how the communication is performed between the tool and MCP5606B.

I could see that it enters in the TAP controller state machine, The tool writes IR ( 0b00011 )and after that reads DR ( 0x2AE4301D ) and there is a lot of more communication that I didn't recognize yet, but, I know that, according to this [document](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN4477.pdf) in section 4.4 page 10, the readed value 0x2AE4301D is the IDCODE of JTAG's MCP5606BF.

After to study Chapter five of MPC5606's reference manual, I expected that the tool would send a 64-bits password, but I didn't found it in communication yet ( the time of communication is too big, almost 10s ).

So I was wondering, how is performed the reading of the flash memory content, and how it is related to Censorship at bootloader?

Comment: it seems this has been mostly answered in your previous question. why are you asking a new one with basically the same content?

Comment: Yes, it is similar, however, when I made the first question I did not have enough knwoledge to make more accurate question and, although I also asked for information about protection and security, the answers were more related about how to visualize the TAP's state machine. I tried to reinforce my doubt making a comment there, but someone told me that in any case, that was a different question, so I made a new question here. I am really sorry if my question seems the same, that was not my intention.

Answer (score 1):

> After to study Chapter five of MPC5606's reference manual, I expected
>   that the tool would send a 64-bits password, but I didn't found it in
>   communication yet ( the time of communication is too big, almost 10s
>   ).

Since we don't have your log, we can't tell if the password is present. Quite possibly your specific device does not have security option enabled or there is  some way around it (e.g. the default password). In any case, you'll likely need to decode the whole log first to make any further assumptions. (John Doe [made some suggestions](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/16479/60) on how to do it)

> So I was wondering, how is performed the reading of the flash memory
>   content, and how it is related to Censorship at bootloader?

Same answer; decode the communication to see how it's performed. I made some hypotheses in [my previous answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/16478/60), but only by examining  the actual process you can know for sure how it works (unless you have documentation, which does not seem to be available here).